# How to indentify kernel processes (processes running with protection ring 0) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, security, operating-system, kernel-module, cybersource

How can we or windows identify or differentiate kernel processes and user/application processes. Based on meta data of process, flags in process table or other.

Answer (score 3):

All drivers run in a single kernel process along with the rest of the kernel.

Process id 0 is the "idle process" and process id 4 (on XP and later) is the kernel "process". If you are in kernel mode you can probably detect the various types by looking at the `KPROCESS` (not stable across versions). You cannot `OpenProcess` the kernel process in user-mode because it is not a normal process.

If you want to detect a [Pico](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wsl/pico-process-overview)/Drawbridge process I have seen claims that [`SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION::HandleCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation) is 0 in them.

I would recommend the [Windows Internals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/resources/windows-internals) books for more information about the Windows kernel design.